# Burninate (or synonymify) [combox]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The [combox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/combox) tag has only <del>26</del> 25 questions and no wiki entry.  All of the questions are about combo boxes, for which the [combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/combobox) tag seems to be authoritative with about 9 thousand questions.

Comment: Googling "combox" didn't return anything that relates to combo box at all... I'd say, burninate.

Comment: This is clearly a typo. I don't think there is a need to synonymify, just edit the tag to combobox (and fix other problems).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As I commented before, this is more of a typo (and/or laziness when selecting the tag) than a 'useless tag that needs to burn'. I have gone through them all and re-tagged them and edited other problems.

Edit: Tag has been deleted by the cleanup process.